Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree just on tablets
This is the skeleton of my statistics.dart file:
class StatisticsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime endDate;
  final List<String> habits;

  const StatisticsScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.startDate,
    required this.endDate,
    required this.habits,
  });

  @override
  StatisticsScreenState createState() => StatisticsScreenState();
}

class StatisticsScreenState extends State<StatisticsScreen> {
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...
  }
}

Everything looks and works as expected on every device I tested it. It includes a chart and some containers with text.
The problem is that on tablets whenever I switch from portrait to landscape and vice versa, I get this error:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [GlobalKey#196b8]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b98e8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3317:15)
#1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3342:8)
#2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1183:19)
#3      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:475:5)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1397:15)
#5      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1318:9)
#6      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1176:5)
#7      _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#8      PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:427:5)
#9      _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
====================================================================================================

Again, everything works and looks as expected on both portrait and landscape, but switching from landscape to portrait on tablets and vice versa gets me this error.
Since this is the only screen that gets this error in my app, it makes me think there is something wrong with how I retrieve the startDate, toDate, and habits values from the previous screen.
